# the interaction between a user and crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

How to realize that?

I need to run a `crontab` task. At some time, there will be a pop-out window to remind me doing  something.

If I input yes in that window, that task will be done, while if no,nothing will happen

`Crontab` just does things in background. How to interact with it?

I could use, say

```
echo 'good' >/dev/pts/1
```

However tty1 does not exists necessarily.

Comment: What is the point of using crontab to have an interactive program?

Comment: `crontab` asks me `do you like to do something now`? There should be a window to display the inquiry of `crontab` and at the same place, I can input yes or no.

Comment: @quesionhang - No it does not. cron only runs programs are certain times during the day. crontab is the file that defines what jobs are executed when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zenity` and make sure to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0.0` when executing zenity from within the crontab as this is necessary to start GUI apps on the X server.

Comment: `zenity` is good. I can input something in a pop-out window. However what I input could not be detected by other scripts. Those scripts need to be run according to what I input.

Comment: @questionhang: You can pass what you input into `zenity` as an argument to another executable, e.g. a script that will run a different set of instructions according to what argument ("yes" or a "no" in this case) it was passed. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @questionhang You do `man zenity` then read the 2nd paragraph that says "For example, zenity --question will return either 0 or 1, depending on whether the user pressed OK or Cancel. zenity --entry will output on standard output what the user typed into the text entry field."

Comment: I use `a=$(zenity --entry)` and can capture what I input. How to capture  0 or 1 by `zenity --entry`?

Comment: @questionhang It's better to use `--question` to capture a 0 or 1, as per the sentence I *just* quoted from the man page.

Comment: `echo $?` could realize that. But there is a problem here. `zenity` is not able to make a pop-out window by `crontab`. `crontab` just sends me mails.There is no pop-out window.

Comment: @questionhang Like I said, you have to run zenity with `DISPLAY=:0.0` environment variable set to be able to run it from cron.

Answer (score 1):

The usual division of labor for a problem like this is to divide the code into a server component and a client component. The server runs in the background, detached from your interactive session, and does any actual work, whilst listening for client connections. You run the client from your GUI, either interactively or as part if your GUI session, and it performs any user interactions and communicates your inputs to the server.

Comment: is there a way to realize that in the same system?

Comment: No, because your crontab entry could run when you are not logged in your system.

Comment: @EdHeal: I rolled back your edit.  If you seriously want to engage in a British vs overseas English war, I think there is a separate site for that in the StackExchange network.